# Selecting records based on a list of id's and keeping the order

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to find records based on a list of id's. But when the records are returned the order is lost.
I need to return the `records` in the same order as it was received in the `list`. How would I do this?

```
// Select Records from list of id's
public IQueryable<Record> GetRecords(List<int> list)
{
    /*
     * Linq to SQL has a limit on 2100
     */
    var records = Enumerable.Empty<Record>().AsQueryable<Records>();
    var limit = 2000;
    var result = list.Select((value, index) => new { Index = index, Value = value })
             .GroupBy(x => x.Index / limit)
             .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Value).ToList())
             .ToList();

     foreach (var r in result)
     {
         var row = r;
         records = records.Union(db.Records.Where(a => row.Contains(a.record_id)));
     }
     return records;
}
```

Comment: Why do not calling `records.OrederBy(x=>x.record_id)` at the end?

Comment: SQL will not be able to keep your order. You must sort result manually in your application.

Comment: @Saeed Wouldn't that just order the records from smallest to largest id and not in the order it was received in the `list`?

Comment: what was the sort order of list? it was arbitrary? or there is some rule?

Comment: Yeah, it's totally up to the user how to sort the list before it is received.

Comment: Does the return type need to be `IQueryable<Record>`?

Comment: Yes, I really need it to be that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is as this:

```
records.Select(x=>new {index = list.IndexOf(x.record_id), record = x})
       .OrderBy(x=>x.index).Select(x=>x.record);
```

This is O(n^2) but may be there is O(n log n) one.

Comment: I found an even easier way: `records.OrderBy(x => list.IndexOf(x.record_id));`

Comment: @Niklas yeah, I don't know why I wrote it so :)